# Creating a button intent to save information

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating an android application that uses data from buttons clicked to generate an answer stored in the shared preferences. I am having trouble finding the necessary intent code to save the information when the user clicked on the button so it can be used to calculate the answer. As you can see from the code when the user clicks the button it will generate the next activity.Thanks!

```
    Button button18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18);
    button18.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //I need to store the results then move to the next activity shown below?
            Intent i = new Intent(EnterAgeActivity.this, EnterWeightActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    `
```

Comment: you can use shared preferences

Comment: So instead of creating an intent i can use the Shared preferences to store and calculate the information?

Comment: with shared preferences you can store the calculated value and retrieve it when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the data with the intent.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //I need to store the results then move to the next activity shown below?
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString(key, value);
    data.putInt(key, value);
    Intent i = new Intent(EnterAgeActivity.this, EnterWeightActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("data", data);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

EnterWeightActivity oncreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtras) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        // Your data
    }
}
```